# Arguments from context returns empty list

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a decorator that checks if the number of arguments given to a command is the right number. So I've done this so far.

```
def has_correct_number_arguments(minimum=None, maximum=None):
    def predicate(ctx):
        print(ctx.args) #returns []
        if minimum is None:
            if maximum is None:
                return False
            else:
                return len(ctx.args) == maximum
        else:
            if maximum is None:
                return minimum <= len(ctx.args)
            else:
                return minimum <= len(ctx.args) <= maximum
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Yet when I'm using it and printing the value of args inside the context it returns an empty list. Does anyone know why or know an another way to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are parsed after the checks, that's why ctx.args will always be empty.